# Meteor.loginWithPassword restrict to admin only

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am looking for a handler that enables me to add a further check on the server side for the meteor account package when calling `Meteor.loginWithPassword`.

I am using roles and want to restrict login to `admin`. I have looked at the documentation and can't find anything.

I know I can check on the client side but would prefer this to be done on the server. Is this possible? I know you can do it when you create a user using `Accounts.onCreateUser`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `validateLoginAttempt` method

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function(attempt){
  //userId is available at "attempt.user._id"

 //check admin or not, return false to abort login

});
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the help